# Self join query using SQL - demo query attached

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where I need my query to pull out data based on Code value.

Example: The table #temp1 has the combination of Person ID, Program assignments and dataset. For any person '1001', I want to pull out the admission date of first program and discharge date and dataset of the last program under similar code 'PS'.

So, my desired output is:

[image]

Demo code:

https://rextester.com/ADDL95491

Any help?!

Comment: which field define last or first for each CID? I mean on which column, rows must be sorted for getting first and last ?

Comment: Program + code combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you need below query

```
with cte1 as
      (select cid,code,admissiondate,dischargedate,program 
        from #temp1 t1 where
       t1.row_number =  (select min(row_number) from #temp1)
      ) , cte2 as
      (select * from  #temp1 where dataset is not null
      )
      select cte1.cid,cte1.code,cte1.admissiondate,
      cte2.dischargedate,cte2.dataset  
      from cte1 left join cte2 on cte1.code=cte2.code
```

https://rextester.com/BNVK71028

```
    cid    code admissiondate   dischargedate   dataset
1   1001    PR  01/01/2011      5/1/2011       discharge data
2   1001    PS  06/01/2011      7/1/2011       discharge data
3   1001    PQ  08/01/2011
```